# Read a HTML file into a string variable in memory

Tags: c#, html, file-io, html-parsing

If I have a HTML file on disk, How can I read it all at once in to a String variable at run time? Then I need to do some processing on that string variable.

Some html file like this:

```
<html>
    <table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" rules="all" border="1" style="border-width:1px;border-style:solid;width:274px;border-collapse:collapse;">
        <COLGROUP><col width=35px><col width=60px><col width=60px><col width=60px><col width=59px></COLGROUP>
        <tr style="height:20px;">
            <th style="background-color:#A9C4E9;"></th><th align="center" valign="middle" style="color:buttontext;background-color:#D3DCE9;">A</th><th align="center" valign="middle" style="color:buttontext;background-color:#D3DCE9;">B</th><th align="center" valign="middle" style="color:buttontext;background-color:#D3DCE9;">C</th><th align="center" valign="middle" style="color:buttontext;background-color:#D3DCE9;">D</th>
        </tr><tr style="height:20px;">
            <th align="center" valign="middle" style="color:buttontext;background-color:#E4ECF7;">1</th><td align="left" valign="top" style="color:windowtext;background-color:window;">Hi</td><td align="left" valign="top" style="color:windowtext;background-color:window;">Cell Two</td><td align="left" valign="top" style="color:windowtext;background-color:window;">Actually a longer text</td><td align="left" valign="top" style="color:windowtext;background-color:window;">Final Word</td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</html>
```

Answer (score 70, accepted):

Use [File.ReadAllText](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.file.readalltext.aspx) passing file location as an argument.

However, if your real goal is to parse html then I would recommend using [Html Agility Pack](http://html-agility-pack.net).

Comment: Do not forget to check if the file exists before you read in the file. :)

Comment: HAP did it for me!

Answer (score 27):

Use `System.IO.File.ReadAllText(fileName)`

Answer (score 20):

```
string html = File.ReadAllText(path);
```

Answer (score 13):

This is mostly covered already, but one addition as I ran into an issue with the previous code samples.

```
Dim strHTML as String = System.IO.File.ReadAllText(HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("~/folder/filename.html"))
```

Answer (score 5):

Use `File.ReadAllText(path_to_file)` to read

Answer (score 5):

You can do it the simple way:

```
string pathToHTMLFile = @"C:\temp\someFile.html";
string htmlString = File.ReadAllText(pathToHTMLFile);
```

Or you could stream it in with FileStream/StreamReader:

```
using (FileStream fs = File.Open(pathToHTMLFile, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.ReadWrite))
{
    using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(fs))
    {
        htmlString = sr.ReadToEnd();
    }
}
```

This latter method allows you to open the file while still permitting others to perform Read/Write operations on the file.  I can't imagine an HTML file being very big, but it has the added benefit of streaming the file instead of capturing it as one large chunk like the first method.

Comment: *This latter method allows you to open the file while still **permitting** others to perform **Read/Write** operations on the file*.

Are you implying the first method **prohibits** others to perform **Read** operations on the file? Because I don't suppose so.

Comment: Waiting for your response @vapcguy

Comment: @om-ha Wasn't trying to imply that at all - honestly, I never tested reading and writing operations at the same time while doing a `File.ReadAllText`. I have tested it with multiple combinations of the latter code block, however. I only meant it as a description for what is in that last block of code because there are various options to use with `FileMode` and `FileAccess` that don't actually work that you might think actually would.

Answer (score 4):

What kind of processing are you trying to do?  You can do `XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();` followed by `doc.Load(filename)`.  Then the XML document can be parsed in memory.

Read here for more information on XmlDocument:

- [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xmldocument.aspx)
- [C# Corner tutorial](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/bulentozkir/ReadingXmlUsingXmlDocument11142005010141AM/ReadingXmlUsingXmlDocument.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

```
var htmlText = System.IO.File.ReadAllText(@"C:/filename.html");
```

And if file in at application root, user below

```
var htmlText = System.IO.File.ReadAllText(HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath(@"~/filename.html"));
```